# ошибки LNK2001 LNK1120

Tags: c++, c

Не могу даже попробовать запустить программу, так как появляется следующее сообщение об ошибках:

[image: LNK2001 LNK1120]
В программировании новичок, понимаю, что использую и с, и с++ в коде, но все же
как исправить ошибку?

```
//дана строка символов состоящая из цифр разделенных пробелами 
//вывести на экран числа этой строки в порядке возрастания их значений
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char str[];
int s=0;
int *arr;
char *context=NULL;
void main()
{
    cout << "Please input the size of a string +1\n";
    cin >> s;
    cout << "Please input a string of numbers which are divided by spaces\n";
    cin >> str[s];
    arr = new int[s];
    arr[0] = atoi(strtok_s(str, " ",&context));
    for (int i = 1; i < s; i++)
    {
        while (str != '\0')
        {
            arr[i] = atoi(strtok_s(__noop," ", &context));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: у вас char str[] объявлен, но не определен. Вот и ошибка линкования. Определите его, указав размер

Comment: укажите размер массива

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov было исправлено, теперь проблема следующая - Debug Assertion Failed! (expression: _p!=nullptr)

Comment: У Вас в задании "дана строка символов состоящая из цифр разделенных пробелами ".То есть строку даже вводить не нужно, она уже дана.

Comment: @JaponDemon даже если пересмотреть задание с такой стороны и взять сразу строку, к примеру, char str [] = "1 223 56 3 67", то все равно ошибка остается

Comment: https://ideone.com/KkfEek

Comment: @JaponDemon в вашем варианте я не могу отсортировать введенные числа

Comment: Только сортировку свою добавьте, а то взял из <algorithm> https://ideone.com/KkfEek

Comment: Даже вот для  строки в которой не только цифры https://ideone.com/Q8eJdN .

Comment: Что здесь делает тег [с]???

Comment: Что делает в коде этот `__noop`? Зачем вы его туда вставили?

Comment: @Yana: Вы привели фейковый код, который не имеет отношения к тому, что вы в реальности пытаетесь компилировать. Приводите реальный код.

Comment: @Alexcei Shmakov: С точки зрения С++ `char str[]` на уровне файла - некорректное объявление. С точки зрения С `char str[]`  - определение массива размера 1. Так что никакого "объявлен, но не определен" тут нет. Только, разве что, из-за самодеятельности какого-то компилятора.

Comment: @AnT, спасибо за детальное уточнение.

Comment: @JaponDemon спасибо

Comment: @AnT  как я могла привести во внимание работающий код, если я не могла запустить этот из-за возникшей проблемы, да, код получился неудачный, но таким образом я пыталась изначально решить поставленную задачу, в итоге не вышло

Answer (score 0):

```
cin >> s;
```

Считано целое число.

```
cout << "Please input a string of numbers which are divided by spaces\n";
cin >> str[s];
```

Даже если объявить `str` с каким-то размером - типа `char str[200]` - что получается? Мы читаем 1 (прописью - *ОДИН*) символ в `s`-й элемент массива. И с чем вы хотите работать?

Но даже если вы исправите на

```
cin >> str;
```

то это приведет к чтению в `str` 1 (опять прописью - *ОДНОГО*) слова, но никак не строки чисел, разделенной пробелами...

Не знаю ваш ограничения (чем можно пользоваться), но вот [один из вариантов решения](https://ideone.com/ufFmp6).

Comment: заменила ввод на     gets_s(str, s),проблема осталась та же; с векторами еще не умею работать, да и суть задания конкретно ввести строку с цифрами, разделенными пробелами, а не числовой массив

Comment: Ну читайте ее сразу в числа! `cin >> N;` - зачем читать ее в строку? Тем более что вы вводите вначале размер строки (количество чисел?)

Comment: мне необходимо считать сразу как строку, в этом и задание, сейчас изучаем функции для обработки строк, поэтому столько мороки

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    char *ptr = nullptr;
    int arr[100], counter = 0;

    // ВВОД СТРОКИ
    std::cin.getline(str, 100);

    // РАЗБИВАЕМ СТРОКУ НА ТОКЕНЫ
    for (ptr = strtok(str, " ,.-"); ptr != nullptr;
         ptr = strtok(nullptr, " ,.-"))
    {
        // ТОКЕН ПЫТАЕМСЯ ПРЕОБРАЗОВАТЬ В ЧИСЛО
        // ЕСЛИ ПРЕОБРАЗОВАНИЕ УСПЕШНО, ЗАНОСИМ ПОЛУЧЕННОЕ ЧИСЛО В МАССИВ
        int conVAlue = strtol(ptr, nullptr, 10);
        if (conVAlue)
        {
            arr[counter] = conVAlue;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    // СОРТИРОВКА МАССИВА ЧИСЕЛ
    std::sort(arr, arr + counter);

    // ВЫВОД
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
}
```

ввод: 
qqqwww 222 33333 ddddd 4
вывод: 
4
222
33333